# How to track changes to a UI form?

Tags: design-patterns, reporting

I would like to be able to track actions that a user makes on a specific UI form.

For example - the user picks a product from a combo box, fills in a text field, etc.
Some fields are conditional, meaning that they become visible only if some prior options are chosen.

I want to be able to track his choices at any given moment - basically I'd like a report that is composed of single events that the user took when filling out the form.

I thought of a variation of [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern:

```
public interface Chain{
    setNextChain(Chain next);
    getNextChain();
    setPrevChain(Chain prev);
    getPrevChain();
}

 public class Field implements Chain {
       // All of the chaining implementation...
       // All of the Action's members... 
       private string[] actionData;
     }

public class Product extends Field{
        // old Product logic  integrated within the chain...
     }

public class AdName extends Field{
       // old Product logic  integrated within the chain...
     }
```

Not sure whether that's the right approach, and would appreciate your thoughts on the design.

Comment: I think you are looking for the Builder pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is OK, but to me it looks more like a list of [Commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). The [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is often used to remember user actions, which can be then easily undone when necessary.

The "chain of responsibility" pattern is not exactly what you need here, because your `Field` objects don't actually need a reference to the previous and next element. The only thing you need a list of actions a user performs. Because of this you don't need the `Chain` interface with getNext()/getPrevious() methods. You can basically keep all `Field` instances in a `List` and navigate the list forwards/backwards.

```
interface Command {
}

class ProductSelection implements Command {
   Product selectedProduct;
}

class AdNameSelecton implements Command {
   String selectedAdName;
}

List<Command> actions = new ArrayList<Command>();

// when user selects product
actions.add(new ProductSelection(product));
// when user selects ad name
actions.add(new AdNameSelection(name));
```